# Can Croston's method handle a series that has a large number of zeros at the end?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, crostons-method

I am trying to implement Croston's method in Python.

The way I understand it, the first step is to take a series of the form:

```
Series = [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,
   0]
```

And split it into two series, an interval series with the time between (non-zero) events and an events series with the values for each event.

```
Intervals = [3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 5]
Events = [3,1,3,1,1,2]
```

Then simple exponential smoothing is applied to each series and the two are combined to provide a final forecast.

The problem with using this approach is that the two following series:

```
Series 1 = [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,
   0]

Series 2 = [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Will generate the exact same forecast, but that doesn't seem right. I assume that series 1 should produce a larger forecast than series 2. In fact, if the number of zeros at the end grows indefinitely, then I would expect my forecast to converge to 0.

Am I getting Croston's method wrong?

Or is this an inherent defect in Croston's method?

What approach would produce different forecasts for Series 1 and Series 2, such that  series 1 has a larger forecast?